# Seaborn Pointplot xticks=Days do not appear in correct order, how to change it

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization, xticks

My xticks of Days (categorical data from data frame) doesn't appear in correct order, how to change it?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(13,6))
houragg = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Day','Seasons'])['bike_count'].mean()).reset_index()
sns.pointplot(data=houragg,x=houragg['Day'],
              y=houragg['bike_count'],
              scale = 0.3,
              hue=houragg['Seasons']).set(title='Count by Day and Seasons')

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0)
```

here is the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `order` parameter of [`seaborn.pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html):

```
from calendar import day_name
order = list(day_name)
# ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

sns.pointplot(data=houragg, x=houragg['Day'], order=order,
              y=houragg['bike_count'],
              scale = 0.3,
              hue=houragg['Seasons']).set(title='Count by Day and Seasons')
```

Alternatively, use an ordered [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) with [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
cat = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
       'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
houragg['Day'] = pd.Categorical(houragg['Day'], categories=cat, ordered=True)
```